# Link to a Document Set in a Workflow Email

Tags: workflow, email, document-set

I am using SharePoint 2010.  We have setup Document Sets to collect contracts from Clients.  The Document Set name is a short version of the client name (no special characters, etc).  On the document set I have a shared field for the Client Legal Name and the ID of the client, which passes down to the documents.  Everything is working great.

Our contract admin wants an email when a new document is updated or created by an person.  I would like to include a link to the Document Set so she can view all of the contract documents for the client.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very easily possible. There are a couple of ways that you can do it.

**The Easy Way**

Create a [SharePoint Deesigner based workflow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMIwayfpKPo) that fires whenever an item changes or is created. Compose the string for your email message and include [the URL](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/building-a-hyperlink-in-an-email-with-sharepoint-designer.aspx) to the document set. Use the [Send an Email](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx) action to send your email. You should probably not send it to the person's email address but to either a group or a distribution list, even if there is only one recipient listed.

**The Advanced Way**

Create a [VisualStudio SharePoint Solution of type EventReceiver](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6moBWo93gaI). This will be a list-item based event receiver that will fire on `ItemCreated` and on `ItemUpdated`. Since I am not certain of your skill level, I am going to leave this as is. If you would like a better explanation, I will add more detail. But at the very least you should know that this is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the information Robert.  I guess I was not clear as to what I was looking for.  I have the email working fine and it links to the documents.  What I am looking for is a link to the Document Set (folder).  I don't see how to specify the folder name.  http://mysite.com/Contracts/[folderNameHere]

Comment: Robert - I guess today is a new day and my brain is working a bit better.  I got it:  The URL should be:  http://mysite.com[%Current Item:Path%]

Answer (score 0):

The URL to get to the folder is to use the Path of the Current item.  So the following does work:  http://mysite.com[%Current Item:Path%]  .  You don't need the / after the site because it is included in the Path.